# Task Scheduler won't show icon in taskbar

Tags: gui

I have a simple java gui app that makes a green or red icon on the taskbar (next to clock on the right).

I made a new scheduled task pointing to my .jar file and everything works, i can see it creates a square on the taskbar but for some reason it doesn't show the green or red icon.

If i run the .jar by double clicking it works. If i run it through .bat it works.

I want to open the .jar file without any other things like console window, etc.

Why doesn't it work?

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("iconOK.jpg");
        Image image = icon.getImage();

        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu();
        trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image);
        tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();

        trayIcon.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });


         try {
            tray.add(trayIcon);
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            System.out.println("TrayIcon could not be added.");
        }
```

Comment: I lost a bit more nerves with this, finaly made a .bat file and made .exe from it and ticked hide the window. So now it works as far as my program goes. But here comes task scheduler. Sometimes it runs 2 instances of my program even though there is nothing in there saying he can start more than 1 (1 condition set and no repetitions if it fails). Starts 2 instances of 1 program and none of the other, conditions set same on both programs. It doesn't detect copies of itself either. All other programs start fine, exept my 2 programs, both of which run fine if manualy started.

Comment: As far as the two instances running.. only count on your code to handle this properly.  You need a [MUTEX](https://mkyong.com/java/java-thread-mutex-and-semaphore-example/) to ensure that there isn't another copy running.  If there is another copy, you simply exit.  And a bat file turned into an exe which launches java is janky at best.  For this part, I would have used the windows scripting host.  And GOOD LUCK! :)

Comment: I would gladly use only .jar file but i simply cannot understand why it will not load the image - its a simple green image in right bottom corner, to remind me that all is good and program is running. It actualy makes spot in the notification bar and if i click on it, the program opens which is fine. Everything works except the image. It makes no sense. I thought maybe it doesnt have rights to access outside files but it access .txt files and writes into them no problem

Answer (score 0):

Well i be damned, i found a solution. I had to replace one line with the other:

This one:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("iconOK.jpg");
```

with this one:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("iconOK.jpg"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I am still having some difficulty. My program will not properly write into files if i run the task through task scheduler. It still works if i manualy do it but not if i do it with task manager. Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 0):

Well interesting, the solution was to add "start in" path in scheduler:

C:\Users\me\Desktop\test

Without any quotes. So path to .jar file/script with no quotes. Nothing in arguments. And path to folder where file is. I am happy :)